# override log4j configuration programmatically: file location for FileAppender

Tags: java, properties, log4j, overriding

is it possible to override the "File" property of an appender that has been configured in the `log4j.properties` without creating a new appender?
And if so - how?

This is the situation: I have two apenders, A1 is a ConsoleAppender and A2 is a FileAppender. A2's "File" points a generic error.log:

`log4j.appender.A2.File=error.csv`

This appender only logs error-level events or worse through

`log4j.appender.A2.Threshold=error`.

Now I want those errors to be written in different files depending on which class caused the error, as there are several classes that instances are being created of.
Being able to see which class created the error(s) fast would be of great help, as it is a lot more helpful then skimming through the error.log looking for the class-tags.

So my idea was to override the "File" property e.g. in the constructors of these newly created classes, so they log errors in different files.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I temporarily solved this by formatting all error logging into a "csv" format, so that I could load it into a spreadsheet programm and filter/sort by class tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For changing log4j properties on runtime visit this link

http://alperkaratepe.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/how-to-change-log4j-properties-at-runtime/

```java
 private void updateLog4jConfiguration(String logFile) { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    try { 
        InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/log4j.properties"); 
        props.load(configStream); 
        configStream.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("Error: Cannot laod configuration file "); 
    } 
    props.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.file", logFile); 
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props); 
 }
```

Comment: ...actually helped twice by now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

Old question (well indexed in google). In addition to OP's requirement, adding additional methods iv'e read about to manipulate `log4j.properties`

---

## Modify loaded `log4j.properties` in runtime

```
private void updateLog4jConfiguration(String logFile) { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 
    try { 
        InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/log4j.properties"); 
        props.load(configStream); 
        configStream.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        System.out.println("Errornot laod configuration file "); 
    } 
    props.setProperty("log4j.appender.FILE.file", logFile); 
    LogManager.resetConfiguration(); 
    PropertyConfigurator.configure(props); 
}
```

- full example is in **[this article](http://alperkaratepe.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/how-to-change-log4j-properties-at-runtime/)**

---

## Setting `log4j.properties` in runtime

#### Can be done manually

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("log4j.logger.org.hibernate", "ERROR");
// ...

LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
```

#### Or by loading a different properties file

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new FileInputStream("/etc/myapp/properties/custom-log4j.properties"));
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(properties);
```

---

## VM Option

You can tell log4j to load a different file using `log4j.configuration` VM option

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///etc/myapp/properties/custom-log4j.properties
```

- if you choose this option, it must be provided in the execution line