# How to setup loglevel, log path and add apenders in Log4jLoggerAdapter class?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am using Slf4j with Log4j in my project.  In the class MyClass I have variables that contains string values for loglevel and logpath and a List of String containing the names of appenders.  I want to programmatically override the values  of these variables that have been configured in the log4j.properties file.  The problem that I have is that the variable LOG is of type Log4jLoggerAdapter class.  This class has no class variables that I could modify nor does it have any setter methods that I could use to setup log level, log path or to add appenders .  Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

Public class MyClass
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a [`ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html). You have to configure your configuration early in your program entry point before any call to underlying `log4j`.

Answer (score 0):

slf4j is only a facade for various logging frameworks. So to change the configuration related to a logging framework, you have to use the classes provided by that logging framework.
For log4j, you have to do

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
LOG.setLevel(..);
```

For file path and other details, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242521/override-log4j-configuration-programmatically-file-location-for-fileappender)