# How to specify the location of custom log4j.configuration when spark-submit to Amazon EMR?

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j, amazon-emr

I am trying to run a spark job in EMR cluster.

I my spark-submit I have added configs to read from log4j.properties

```
--files log4j.properties --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/log4j.properties"
```

Also I have added

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/log/test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %5p %c{7} - %m%n
```

in my log4j configurations.

Anyhow I see the logs in the console, though I don't see the log file generated. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting `spark-submit --help`:

> **--files FILES** Comma-separated list of files to be placed in the working directory of each executor. File paths of these files in executors can be accessed via `SparkFiles.get(fileName)`.

That doesn't much say what to do with the `FILES` if you cannot use  `SparkFiles.get(fileName)` (which you cannot for log4j).

Quoting `SparkFiles.get`'s [scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$):

> Get the absolute path of a file added through `SparkContext.addFile()`.

That does not give you much either, but *suggest* to have a look at the [source code of SparkFiles.get](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.scala#L30-L31):

```
def get(filename: String): String =
  new File(getRootDirectory(), filename).getAbsolutePath()
```

The nice thing about it is that `getRootDirectory()` [uses an optional property or just the current working directory](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.scala#L36-L37):

```
def getRootDirectory(): String =
  SparkEnv.get.driverTmpDir.getOrElse(".")
```

That gives as something to work on, *doesn't it?*

On the driver the so-called `driverTmpDir` directory should be easy to find in Environment tab of web UI (under Spark Properties for `spark.files` property or Classpath Entries marked as "Added By User" in Source column).

On executors, I'd *assume* a local directory so rather than using `file:/log4j.properties` I'd use

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file://./log4j.properties
```

or

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties
```

Note the dot to specify the local working directory (in the first option) or no leading `/` (in the latter).

Don't forget about `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` to set the Java options for the driver if that's something you haven't thought about yet. You've been focusing on executors only so far.

You may want to add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to `spark.executor.extraJavaOptions` that is supposed to print what locations log4j uses to find `log4j.properties`.

---

I have not checked that answer on a EMR or YARN cluster myself but believe that may have given you some hints where to find the answer. *Fingers crossed!*

Comment: spark-submit --class com.myapp.cloud.app.UPApp --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 8 --files log4j.properties --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file://./log4j.properties" --conf "spark.eventLog.dir=/mnt/var/log/" uber-up-0.0.1.jar                I am trying to run this an still I dont see any log files created at location /log/test.log

Answer (score 3):

With Spark 2.2.0 standalone cluster, executor JVM is started first and only then Spark distributes application jar and --files
Which means passing

> spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-spark.xml

does not makes sense as this file does not exist yet (is not downloaded) at the executor JVM launch time and log4j initialization

If you pass

> spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-spark.xml

you will find at the beginning of the executor's stderr failed attempt to load log4j config file

```
log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [file:log4j-spark.xml].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j-spark.xml (No such file or directory)
...
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
```

And bit later is logged download of --files from driver

```
18/07/18 17:24:12 INFO Utils: Fetching spark://123.123.123.123:35171/files/log4j-spark.xml to /ca/tmp-spark/spark-49815375-3f02-456a-94cd-8099a0add073/executor-7df1c819-ffb7-4ef9-b473-4a2f7747237a/spark-0b50a7b9-ca68-4abc-a05f-59df471f2d16/fetchFileTemp5898748096473125894.tmp
18/07/18 17:24:12 INFO Utils: Copying /ca/tmp-spark/spark-49815375-3f02-456a-94cd-8099a0add073/executor-7df1c819-ffb7-4ef9-b473-4a2f7747237a/spark-0b50a7b9-ca68-4abc-a05f-59df471f2d16/-18631083971531927447443_cache to /opt/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/work/app-20180718172407-0225/2/./log4j-spark.xml
```

It may work differently with yarn or another cluster manager but with standalone cluster, it seems there is no way you can specify your own logging configuration for executors on spark-submit.

You can dynamically reconfigure log4j in your job code ([override log4j configuration programmatically: file location for FileAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242521/override-log4j-configuration-programmatically-file-location-for-fileappender)), but you would need to do it carefully in some mapPartition lambda that is executed in executor's JVM. Or maybe you can dedicate first stage of your job to it. All that sucks though...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete command I used to run my uber-jar in EMR and I see log files generated in driver and executor nodes.

spark-submit --class com.myapp.cloud.app.UPApp --master yarn --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 8 --files log4j.properties --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties -Dlog4j.debug=true" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties" --conf "spark.eventLog.dir=/mnt/var/log/" uber-up-0.0.1.jar

where log4j.properties is in my local filesystem.